# /page/feed post made via API with object_attachment shows empty square where photo should be

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Using this code,

```
    $fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
        'app_id'                => FB_APP_ID,
        'app_secret'            => FB_APP_SECRET,
        'default_graph_version' => 'v2.9'
    ]);

    //Post property to Facebook
    $linkData = [
        'link' => 'http://www.example.com/',
        'message' => 'test message',
        'object_attachment' => 111111111111111
    ];

    try {
        $response = $fb->post('/mypageid/feed', $linkData, FB_APP_ACCESS_NON_EXPIRES);
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
        echo 'Graph returned an error: '.$e->getMessage();
        exit;
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
        echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: '.$e->getMessage();
        exit;
    }
    $graphNode = $response->getGraphNode();
```

I get this result:

[image: Missing the photo included]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I just checked this with the Graph Api Explorer and obviously the image is missing as soon as `link` and `object_attachment` are set. Setting only one of these fields is working as expected. BTW only `link` and `object_attachment` isn't working either. Perhaps this is a bug, I suggest you check the Facebook bugs, or create a new one ;)

Comment: @Norbert, I think this might rather have to do with their removal of all possibilities to specify additional data such as title, description, thumbnail for posted links, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_9_90_day_deprecations

Comment: Maybe, but leaving the image empty is a bit strange ...

Comment: I think the reason they've removed `picture` is so we use 'object_attachment` instead, @CBroe ?

Comment: I have created a new bug @Norbert - let's see if anything comes of it! https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/108561999771757

Comment: FB have confirmed that this is a bug - I've no idea how such a popular action (it must be one of the most common things to perform with the API?!) can go unreported until little old me finds it, but there you go!